# Pytorch loss function for Levenshtein (edit) distance between letters in images

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

Is it possible to use the Levenshtein (edit) distance of two strings as the error function my model attempts to optimize?

The inputs are images representing the letters in a text document. The output should be the predicted letters from the image. I want to combine them into a text document, and then adjust the model weights to minimize the levenshtein distance of the input document, and the predicted document. Can I do this by extending `nn.Module` to create a loss function in `pytorch`, and then using `loss.backward` to update the weights in the model?

Comment: Assuming you have a way to get the characters differentiably (maybe via Gumbel-softmax?), then you need to be able to compute/estimate the edit distance (almost everywhere) differentiably so that the backprop will run. Based on a cursory look this might work.